# WCF4 service host fileless activation configuration error

Tags: wcf, configuration

Hi guys would really appreciate a fix for this its driving me mad.

Using VS2010 SP1 + .Net 4.0 + IIS 7.5 Express.

A simple web project intended to host a WCF service throws a configuration exception for no apparent reason. Host is an empty web application using fileless activation.

Basically as follows :

```
namespace MyWCFServices
{
public class HelloWorldService: IHelloWorldService
    {

        public string GetMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello world from {0}!", name);
        }
    }

 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetMessage(string name);
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment >
        <serviceActivations>
          <add relativeAddress="HelloWorldService.svc" 
               service="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService"/>       
        </serviceActivations>     
      </serviceHostingEnvironment>     
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>         
          </behavior>       
        </serviceBehaviors>     
      </behaviors>   
    </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

Exception:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element.

Source Error:

```
Line 3:      <system.web>
Line 4:          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 5:      </system.web>
Line 6:      <system.serviceModel>
Line 7:        <serviceHostingEnvironment >
```

---Edit:

Same problem on the IIS forums: http://forums.iis.net/t/1180211.aspx/1

The answer is pretty poor: 'perhaps iis-express doesn't support file-less activation'.

Can anyone provide a better answer?

Cheers,
Amax

Answer (score 1):

Strange.  I jus copied your xml and pasted into my project and it worked just fine.  Maybe you have a hidden character in your file????  Try cutting it and pasting into notepad, then copy it back from notepad back into a new web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Rick looks like your suspicion was correct.

I retyped the config file from scratch and problem solved.

IIS should produce a descriptive error in this case, it's misleading to just see 'unrecognized element'.

Comment: This should have been a comment in Ricks answer, also if his answer was correct mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element.

The solution for me was setting up my website as an IIS application and setting the application pool to a 4.0 framework with integrated managed pipeline mode.